# Creating an own Collection type of objects of type "Type" in C#

Tags: c#, collections

I am new to C# and i have the following problem:

I need to create a TypeCollection, that inherits from Collection and the type of objects in here are some types created by me.

In the InsertItem() overloaded method, i want to check if the object is from the specific type hierarchy that i created, else i throw an exception.

The code snippet is attached:

```
public class ObjectTypeCollection<Type> : Collection<Type>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Type item)
    {   
        if(!(Utility.IsFDTObject(item.GetType())))
        {          
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} is not valid", item.ToString()));
        }
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

The problem here is with the item instance. It doesnot have any method which allows me to get the currently passed Type. The GetType() doesnot return me the type that i have passed. Currently, i have used :

```
System.Type typ = System.Type.GetType(item.ToString());
```

to get the type and then passed this to the Utility method. This works fine. Is this the right approach?

Could you please help me here?

Comment: `GetType` gets you the type that an item *is*. What do you mean by "the type that I have passed"?

Comment: You totally confused me there by using `Type` as the generic parameter name.

Comment: the last reply solved my problem. I used IsAssignableFrom() to achieve the requirement. I used Type as it is supposed to be a collection of Types.

Comment: @user1064490 then i suggest you remove the `<Type>` after the class name `ObjectTypeCollection`. Because currenly, the word `Type` is not used as what you meant it to be (`System.Type`), but as a generic type argument name, i.e. users could also instantiate an `ObjectTypeCollection<int>`, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) method:

```
public class FDTObject {}
public class MyDTObject1 : FDTObject {}
public class MyDTObject2 : FDTObject { }

public class ObjectTypeCollection : Collection<Type>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Type item)
    {
        if (!typeof(FDTObject).IsAssignableFrom(item))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} is not valid", item));
        }
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var collection = new ObjectTypeCollection();  
collection.Add(typeof(MyDTObject1)); // ok  
collection.Add(typeof(MyDTObject2)); // ok  
collection.Add(typeof(String)); // throws an exception
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a constraint on type parameter `Type`, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx

This is statically checked and you don't need to do anything dynamic like you're currently doing. Specifically:

`public class ObjectTypeCollection<T> : Collection<T> where T : <base class name>`

Comment: I think, topic-starter wants a collection of System.Type, which members are derived from some base type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) to check if an instance of a Type is assignable from an instance of another Type (if they are compatible). Like this:

```
if (typeof(FDTObject).IsAssignableFrom(item))
```

But your question is a bit unclear. Maybe you don't want to insert actual types but rather objects of a specific type and be able to instantiate the Collection with different types? Then you could constrain the generic parameter in your class:

```
public class ObjectTypeCollection<T> : Collection<T> where T: FDTObject
```

Or you just want a collection where all objects are an FDTObject or descendants of it. Then you could just use a `List<FDTObject>` and you have instant static type checking (the best solution if that is what you itended):

```
List<FDTObject> fdtList = new List<FDTObject>();
```

For me, it's still quite unclear though. Do you want to add instances of `System.Type` to the collection (then you would need to remove the first generic argument directly after the class name)? Or did you just happen to choose `Type` as the name for your generic parameter (which is a bad choice since there's already a type, namely `System.Type` named like that)?

Comment: Thanks! The IsAssignable worked. I used it before, but i used it the other way around. item.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(FDTObject)) which was obviously wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missunderstanding what you want, can't you just use the [generic list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)?

You can initialize the list with the type parameter set to your base class:

```
var list = new List<FDTObject>(); // assuming this is one of your base classes based upon your example.
```

you can then add any object to the list that is an `FDTObject` or inherits from `FDTObject`